# Multiple three dimension checkbox array in php

Tags: php

I am loading data into page like this:

```
<?php while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
<tr name = "row + <?php $row?>">
<td style = display:none><input type="testbox" name=pageID[] value =<?=$result["PageID"]?>></td> 
<td width = 350 ><?php echo $result["PageName"]; ?></td> 
<td width =75> <input type="checkbox" name="AddLis[]" checked value = True ></td>
<td width =75> <input type="checkbox" name="EditLis[]" checked value = True ></td>
<td width =75> <input type="checkbox" name="ViewLis[]" checked value = True ></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

How can I get relevant value in post method.

Comment: At least `<tr name = "row + <?php $row?>">` will not work, because you need to echo $row, and this should be an integer or string.

Answer (score 0):

echo the value you want to add to html snippet

```
***<?php while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
    <tr name = "row + <?php echo $row?>">
    <td style = display:none><input type="testbox" name=pageID[] value ="<?=echo $result["PageID"]?>" ></td> 
    <td width = 350 ><?php echo $result["PageName"]; ?></td> 
    <td width =75> <input type="checkbox" name="AddLis[]" checked value = True ></td>
    <td width =75> <input type="checkbox" name="EditLis[]" checked value = True ></td>
    <td width =75> <input type="checkbox" name="ViewLis[]" checked value = True ></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile;?>***
```